# Tex escapes in Hot Questions sidebar

Tags: bug, hot-questions, latex

As seen on Worldbuilding:

[image]

linked question: [How to add overline on top of $\bm B$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300120/how-to-add-overline-on-top-of-bm-b)

Comment: Heh, so this is funny... There's a check that disallows questions with MathJax in the title from appearing in the hot list, but it only runs on questions from sites that have MathJax enabled. Tex is not one of them. Of course, that title wasn't intended to render - the Tex is part of the question. But when listed on a site with MathJax enabled...